# Drop-down value not showing on front page

Tags: php, html, ajax, dropdownbox

There is a xyz dropdown on the basis if this I am hitting AJAX get data but the response data I got in console but the data is not rendering in front view dropdown.

Here is my html and php code. I got the value it's just not showing in front view:

```
<tr>
    <td class="style2"> District </td>
    <td><select name= "district" id="district_response" class="span6 chzn-select" >
            <option value="">Select District</option>

      </select></td>
  </tr>
```

PHP code

```
<?php $con = mysqli_connect("hostname","username","password","DBname")    or die (mysql_error());


$sname = $_POST['state_select'];
 $sq = "SELECT distinct(bank_district)  FROM bank_all whereb ank_state  ='".$_POST['state_select']."' order BY bank_district ASC";

$result1 = mysqli_query($con,$sq) or die('Error'.mysqli_error());
$resul1="";
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){$resul1.= "<option  value ='{$row["bank_district"]}' >{$row["bank_district"]}</option>";}echo $resul1;?>







function jsFunction(){
 var myselect = $('#state_response').val();
 jQuery.ajax({
    url: "districtajax.php",
    global: false,
    type: "POST",
    data: ({  
        state_select:myselect,

    }),
    dataType: "html",
    async: false,        
    success: function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    //return false;
        $('#district_response').html(msg);
    }
});
}


</script>
```

Comment: You're mixing MySQL APIs using `mysql_error()` which do not intermix with `mysqli_` functions, which **also** doesn't help you.

Comment: This is not the issue. I can see the data in console. But not on the page